# How to deserialize JSON array with "root" element for each object in array using Json.NET?

Tags: .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have following JSON string:

```
[
  { "Person" : { "Name" : "John", "Gender" : "male" } },
  { "Person" : { "Name" : "John", "Gender" : "male" } }
]
```

(As you may notice unfortunately I have a sort of "root" element for each object in the array. Without this "root" element the task becomes quite trivial.)

I have to deserialize it into a list of `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
...
List<Person> ListPersons() {
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonString);
}
```

Is it possible to do with [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) without creating wrapper class like PersonResult?

```
class PersonResult {
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
...
List<Person> ListPersons() {
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonResult>>(jsonString)
                      .Select(p => p.Person)
                      .ToList();
}
```

The perfect solution for me is to be able somehow explicitly specify this "root" (e.g. via attribute) and do not create any wrappers, helpers, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, there's not much you can do about this issue. That's how JSON format looks like and there's no way around that. As a result, Json.Net "sees" your string as more or less:

> *an array of objects with `Person` property, which is another object with `Name` and `Gender` properties*

You could possibly play some with custom [ContractResolvers](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ContractResolver.html) to force serializer to work differently... but that's quite a bit of work. Wrapper class like you suggested is how those problems are dealt with, and I suggest sticking to it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I had to end up with wrapper approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PersonResult : List<Person> {}

class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

main() {
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonResult>(jsonString);
}
```